# std::queue::pop() operation on its std::unique_ptr data

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

I just wonder what will happen if std::queue::pop() is performed on its `std::unique_ptr` data which is `nullptr`. Please consider the code snippet as below,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

class sample
{
    public:
    int data;
    sample() {cout << "\n Constructor Called" << endl;}
    ~sample() {cout << "\n Destructor Called" << endl;}
};

void func(queue<pair<string, unique_ptr<sample>>> & q)
{
    pair<string, unique_ptr<sample>> p = std::move(q.front());

    try
    {
       q.pop();
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        cout << "\n Exception occured" << endl;
    }
}

int main() 
{
    queue<pair<string, unique_ptr<sample>>> q;
    q.push((make_pair("sample obj", unique_ptr<sample>(new sample))));
    func(q);
    return 0;
}
```

While working with the `queue` data in the `func`, I use `std::move` as copy constructor and assignment operator overload functions are deleted in `std::unique_ptr`. This effectively moves the `queue` content to `pair<string, unique_ptr<sample>> p` (please correct me if I'm wrong here) and `unique_ptr` becomes nullptr, and what will happen if I perform `q.pop`. Ideally the `std::queue::pop` will call the destructor of the oldest element which is retrieved using `q.pop()`, can perform `delete` on `nullptr`?.

Comment: I think I don't fully get your concern? `delete nullptr;` is a perfectly valid operation.

Comment: as already mentioned, `delete nullptr` is no-op. Furthermore, `~unique_ptr` doesn't call `deleter` function for `nullptr`, so this code is completely fine even if `deleter` function doesn't check against `nullptr`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is fine.

After `pair<string, unique_ptr<sample>> p = std::move(q.front());`, the element of `queue` is moved, its status is indeterminate but still valid; including being destructible.

Then `q.pop();` will remove the element from the `queue`, and destroy the element. As explained above the element will be destroyed without problem.

> can perform `delete` on `nullptr` ?

After moved the status of object remains valid means you don't need to worry about it. But the straightforward answer to your question is yes, it's fine; the standard library deallocation functions do nothing for it.

Comment: It is worth noting that unique_ptr works in all move-aware containers, analogous to what we see in this question. And a moved-from object should be in a destructible state.